# rspec testing for get/post error responses

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a http GET error response message and can't seem to find any info or examples of this

The expected error response is:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "code": 400,
  "message": "ERROR: This is the specific error message"
}
```

This catches the "Bad Request" but how to verify the "message" in the body of the error response?

```
expect {get "<url that generates a bad request>"}.to raise_error(/400 Bad Request/)
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 9):

In adding to this:

```
it 'returns 400 status' do
  get '/my_bad_url'
  expect(response.status).to eq 400
end
```

you can write

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["message"]).to eq("ERROR: This is the specific error message")
```

or without JSON.parse if you render html.

Comment: (I should have mentioned that I'm using rspec 2.4.1)

When I try this my script never gets past the 'get' line, rspec reports:

    RestClient::BadRequest:
           400 Bad Request

It never gets a chance to check the response?

Answer (score 6):

Request returns response, not exception:

```
it 'returns 400 status' do
  get '/my_bad_url'
  expect(response.status).to eq 400
end
```

Also you can read [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-1/docs/controller-specs), to understand controller specs better.